# get all file names from specific path using javascript/html5/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

i need a logic that can give me all file names in that particular path.

my path is like //ad/zip...  not like c://

Comment: in browser env you cant access the disk drive without user intervention. unless its a cordova or any packaged hybrid app

Comment: i have access.its shared one..within our network we can access..

Comment: I think it was only Chrome that implemented a limited file API, but I'm not even sure that's still around.

Comment: actually i want to get all zip file names from a directory..

Comment: Yes, that was clear from your question. Chrome was the only browser (that I am aware of) that implemented **any** kind of file API such as what you would need. Otherwise you have to use a `type="file"` input and allow the user to browse for files. You can limit it to only show `.zip` files, but that's about the best you can do.

Comment: actually i want to get all zip files and populate the names in search box.my path is like //ad/zip....